# NSManagedObjectContext and SplitViewController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uisplitviewcontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

[image: This is my storyboard]

I am trying to use a SplitViewController to pass my NSManagedObjectContext through to my Master view controller.
Everything works fine when using an iPhone and no split view.  The category tableview on my master view controller (ViewController) shows my data.  However, when I use an iPad, the tableview is empty.

On the iPhone, when I select a row in the top tableview, it displays the related objects in the lower tableview.  Selecting an object on the lower tableview performs the segue to my detail view controller's navigation controller but I don't even get there on the iPad because the top tableview is not populated.

In my AppDelegate, I have the following.
Any ideas why it will display the content on an iPhone when there is no split view, but not on an iPad when it is split?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
        splitViewController.delegate = self
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
            splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .AllVisible
            splitViewController.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 0.5
            splitViewController.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 400
        }
        let nav = splitViewController.viewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController
        let vc = nav.topViewController as! ViewController
        let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.MainQueueConcurrencyType)
        context.persistentStoreCoordinator = CDHelper.sharedInstance.coordinator
        vc.context = context
        return true
    }
```

I also have this

```
func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController:UIViewController, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController:UIViewController) -> Bool {
        guard let secondaryAsNavController = secondaryViewController as? UINavigationController else { return false }
        guard let topAsDetailController = secondaryAsNavController.topViewController as? ColorPickerViewController else { return false }
        if topAsDetailController.paletteColor == nil {
            // Return true to indicate that we have handled the collapse by doing nothing; the secondary controller will be discarded.
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```

Comment: Why you aren't using already provided `lazy var managedObjectContext` in AppDelegate?

Comment: @njuri I am using my own Core Data helper and not the one generated by selecting Core Data at the start of the project so it is defined there.

Comment: Are you using an `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate your tables?